# Discover projection of a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, utm

Some shapefiles with data supposed to be located in Michigan, USA, were sent to me.
The attribute table shows coordinates such as :

```
X               Y 
1929418       287864
1467373       543238
```

I assumed this would be UTM projection, likely to be WGS1984 UTM 16N.

However, when defining the projection as such, the data is plotted around the Andes in Colombia...

Is there a way to find out what the original projection used is?

Comment: Did the shapefile not come with the .prj file?

Answer (score 1):

Projfinder:

http://projfinder.com/

enter the coordinates you have (try both ways round if not sure), zoom to roughly where you think the points should be, and it will find projections that map those coordinates to that part of the world.

It tells me your first point would be in Michigan if its in EPSG:26813 coordinates.

Comment: Thank you, how would I find this projection in ArcGIS pro? It doesn't seem to be among the options?

Comment: I don't know - does ArcGIS Pro not let you set EPSG projections? I don't know, don't use it. You can look it up at epsg.io and get it in ESRI WKT form: https://epsg.io/26813 but I don't know where you stick that in ArcGIS Pro. You could also try creating a .prj file component of your shapefile with the proj.4 version of the CRS text and then most GIS should recognise it. Did you not get a .prj with your .shp, .shx, and .dbf? Did you even get those parts?

Comment: EPSG: 26813 is deprecated and it's not in ArcGIS; it was on an adjusted ellipsoid. Try Michigan GeoRef (called Michigan Oblique Mercator in EPSG). Or one of the NAD27 zones, but it could be any of the 3 (north, central, south).